# What environmental and ecological effect would a massive wind turbine mountain construct have on it's surroundings to an indefinite distance?

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, environment, ecology

For the contest, the construct is a massive tetrahedron shaped construct that extends into the lower stratosphere of a roughly earth-like planet with several holes, tunnels in it containing wind turbines (bladed), arranged in such a way as to extract the maximum amount of energy the possibly could(from the wind, I mean, and so with the BASE having ROUGHLy the area impact on land of ROUGHLY 780 square kilometers, and is comprised primarily of carbon nanotubes and materials which maximize and eliminate. skin friction. It's primary purpose is to turn the winds kinetic and thermal energy into electry, eg with a secondary function as a differential heat generator The question is this

**What would the impact be of such a construct on its surroundings to an indefinite distance?**

Comment: I don't have a clear vision of the construct from your description, other than something really big shaped like a 4-sided die that somehow has tunnels in it to collect wind power. Why a tetrahedron? What's the function? Understanding what and why may be important to understanding impact. What contest are you referring to? The bottom triangle has a surface area of 780 square kilometers, or the upper three sides, or the whole thing? What is it made of? Does it move? Is it in a migratory pathway? What kind of wind turbines?

Comment: It works like a massive collection of wind turbines and a geothermal power plant using the temperature different between the ground and the upper atmosphere

Comment: And it does not move

Comment: It's normally considered best to wait a decent interval (24 hours is normally mentioned in this respect) before choosing a best answer rather than just ticking the first one as soon as it appears

Comment: Why have you capitalised some words in the question? Is there some special significance to "ROUGHLY" and "BASE"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your building would have a very broad range of effects in many categories.

Physical Effects

- Your giant structure acts in many ways like a very large mountain. Even if wind turbines form a large part of its surface area, to generate energy wind resistance is required. Therefore, expect air to be channeled around your structure much like a mountain.
- As air hits your structure, much like a mountain it may rise. If so it will carry with it moisture, and much like a mountain you would have precipitation on one side of it, and none on the other.

Ecological Effects

- If your wind turbines are not protected, expect birdlife and local fauna to have to adapt to your building. One would expect some may initially die if colliding with the turbines, however they would quickly adapt and manage the issue.
- Expect many types of fauna to inhabit your building. Unless copiously maintained, a building with many holes such as yours would house many rodents, spiders, insects and indeed even birds.
- Regarding Flora - if your building is not on the equator, there would be an area adjacent that would be in constant shadow. Significant plant life in this area will not grow, but moss, shrubs and lichen would dominate this area.

Sociological Effects

- This object is significant in the landscape, and human cultures would see it from very far away - from a distance much further than mountains. This would quickly become a symbol of progress, or significant in terms of cultural impact.

Economic Effects

- Keep in mind a building has more presence than just its physical effects. All buildings consume resources to construct and has far reaching implications well-beyond its immediate surroundings.
- The size of this building may cost billions to build, may cost millions every year to maintain, and is a significant investment for people to accomplish and keep functional. Such a building would be made at the cost of others - for instance hospitals, other infrastructure projects and housing. The 'effect' of a building thus affects the entire economy and human social construct.

Comment: I forgot to add: On the last point Economic effects a building of this type would consume a lot of steel, concrete and other materials, so somewhere else (or close by) are large quarries and mines, with processing and refinement plants. As such, this building will effect land far away from it, and also its commensurate production of carbon in the atmosphere. Expect too maintenance crews to require nearby towns, which also consume resources of food and materials, all of which have a further ecological effect.

Comment: /////////Thanks.//////////

Comment: For the sociological effects. apparently we have been there, done that, got the t-shirt. The Tower of Babel, and we were punished for our vanity. https://www.christianity.com/wiki/sin/what-can-we-learn-from-the-tower-of-babel-in-the-bible.html

Comment: //I'm atheist, but sure//

Comment: //The primary purpose, of the construct that is/was to generate electricity, for context. I don't think that was ever stated outright.

Comment: /////////duh///////////

Comment: As in, it had no secondary purpose beyond generating electricity.

Comment: I'm just talking to myself Thbbbbbb(smacks head).

Comment: My head I mean, for talking to myself in a long comment thread.